# Not able to setup URL Scheme and callback url in Square Connect

Tags: ios, swift, square-connect

I need to integrate square payment gateway in my iOS app. I've downloaded their swift example, added a dependency to it. Set up the app on the developer portal. Given this "innovation" under app URL Schemes. This is the code for calling payment gateway API.

```
 let currencyCodeString = currencyField.text?.nilIfEmpty ?? currencyField.placeholder!
    let amountString = amountField.text?.nilIfEmpty ?? amountField.placeholder!

    let amount: SCCMoney
    guard let amountCents = Int(amountString) else {
        showErrorMessage(title: "Invalid Amount", message: "\(amountString) is not a valid amount.")
        return
    }

    do {
        amount = try SCCMoney(amountCents: amountCents, currencyCode: currencyCodeString)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        showErrorMessage(title: "Invalid Amount", error: error)
        return
    }

    let userInfoString = userInfoStringField.text?.nilIfEmpty
    let merchantID = merchantIDField.text?.nilIfEmpty
    let customerID = customerIDField.text?.nilIfEmpty
    let notes = notesField.text?.nilIfEmpty

    let request: SCCAPIRequest
    do {
        request = try SCCAPIRequest(callbackURL: yourCallbackURL,
                                    amount: amount,
                                    userInfoString: userInfoString,
                                    merchantID: merchantID,
                                    notes: notes,
                                    customerID: customerID,
                                    supportedTenderTypes: supportedTenderTypes,
                                    clearsDefaultFees: clearsDefaultFees,
                                    returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        showErrorMessage(title: "Invalid Amount", error: error)
        return
    }

    do {
        try SCCAPIConnection.perform(request)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        showErrorMessage(title: "Cannot Perform Request", error: error)
        return
    }
```

and I'm using this as callback URL

```
let yourCallbackURL = URL(string: "innovation://callback")!
```

included the values in Info.plist

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.squareup.hellocharge</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>innovation</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>square-commerce-v1</string>
</array>
```

But still, I'm getting this error "Can't perform request. ensure that "square-commerce-v1" is included in the LSApplicationQuerySchemes in your info.plist and the square point of sale is installed on your device".

Comment: Which version of Square Point of Sale do you have on your device? Also your code says `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` instead of `LSApplicationQuerySchemes`

Comment: @tristansokol I'm using sdk version 3.0 and i have written LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in every app. but still i changed and tried with no success.

Comment: Which version of the Square Point of Sale app do you have on the device? You must install that app as well.